# Generating a random email using python 3.2

Tags: python, random

I would like to generate a 64 letter for a random email. There are a few restriction so as to follow the email syntax. But I am not sure why doesnt my output display anything. Is there something wrong with my if statement?

```
import random
y=" "
for x in range (0,64): 
     z = random.randint(33,127)
     if z in [32,34,40,41,44,58,59,60,62,64,91,92,93] == False:
          b = chr(z)
          print(b)
```

Comment: What you need to do is `if z not in [32,34,40,41,44,58,59,60,62,64,91,92,93]`. `z in [32,34,40,41,44,58,59,60,62,64,91,92,93] == False` will always evaluate to `False`

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if z in [32,34,40,41,44,58,59,60,62,64,91,92,93] == False:
```

is equivalent to:

```
if z in [32,34,40,41,44,58,59,60,62,64,91,92,93] and [32,34,40,41,44,58,59,60,62,64,91,92,93] == False:
```

which never evaluates to True, you probably meant to do:

```
if z not in [32,34,40,41,44,58,59,60,62,64,91,92,93]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice way to do what you want:

```
import random

invalid_choices = [32,34,40,41,44,58,59,60,62,64,91,92,93]
valid_choices = list(set(range(33,127)) - set(invalid_choices))

def generate_content(length):
    return [pick_letter() for _ in range(length)]

def pick_letter():
    return chr(random.choice(valid_choices)
```

Using the code:

```
>>> generate_content(10)
['Z', 'o', 'q', '~', 'a', 'O', '2', 'p', 's', '3']
```

You can use any number and you will get a list of random characters according to the specified choices you gave in your original post.

To turn that into a string you can do:

```
>>> ' '.join(generate_content(10))
'! 3 * X 7 R s X } d'
```